# Google Directory API Returning "403 - Insufficient Permission" error when trying to execute request to obtain GROUPS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-directory-api, google-groups

Actual error message:

> Unhandled Exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Insufficient Permission [403]
>   Errors [
>           Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
>   ]

It only throws this error when I try to access **GROUPS**. I can obtain the users just fine. Here is my code:

```
private static readonly int maxResultsReturned = 500;
private static readonly string ApplicationName = "Directory API .NET Quickstart";
private static readonly string[] Scopes = { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly,
                                            DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly
};

public static void getGroups()
{
    var service = setUpService();

    // Define parameters of request.
    var request = service.Groups.List();
    request.Customer = "my_customer";
    request.MaxResults = maxResultsReturned;

    IList<Group> groups = request.Execute().GroupsValue; //Error thrown here

    foreach (Group groupItem in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", groupItem);
    }
}
```

Error is thrown when calling `IList<Group> groups = request.Execute().GroupsValue;`

Is there something I'm missing? I tried including all of the scopes that `DirectoryService` holds, but still getting the same error.

Anyone have any input?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having the right scope the user you are impersonating (if using a service account) or running the script as must also have the rights set in the admin console. This may be the case, it was for me a couple of days ago.